# Copy columns' data to other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

#### My data is like this:

[image: Data Source]

#### This is my desired output:

[image: Final Data (this is what I want)]

I haven't tried any code.

I'm a novice in Visual Basic for Applications;
any suggestions on how to proceed will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ***need*** a VBA solution? 
This can be handled easily through normal, manual operation of the Excel GUI:

1. Copy all the data to the new sheet. 
   On the new sheet …
2. Select Column `C` (or `D`).
3. In the “Data” tab, “Sort & Filter” panel, click on “Filter”. 
   A downward-pointing arrow will appear in cell `C1`.
4. Click on that arrow. 
   A pop-up will appear. 
   In the lower half of that pop-up,
   click the checkbox next to “(Select All)” to clear all the checkboxes,
   then click the checkbox next to “(Blanks)” to turn it back on. 
   Click on “OK”.
5. You should now see only the rows that have nothing in Column `C`
   (i.e., for your example, Rows 3, 4, 8, 9 and 11 will be hidden).
6. Select the data rows that are visible; i.e., 5 through 12. 
   Actually, only Rows 5, 6, 7, 10 and 12 will be selected. 
   Delete those rows
   (e.g., by right-clicking in the selected region and selecting “Delete Row”).
7. Click on the “Filter” button in the ribbon again
   to remove the filter and restore the full view of your data,
   which has Dates and Descriptions 1, 5, 6 and 8 in Rows 4 through 7.